# How to remove duples from list of objects?

Tags: c#

I have a list:

```
public class myObject(){
  public string Id {get;set}
  public string Name {get;set}
}

var list = new List<MyObject>();
```

Now  i want remove all dups from list:

```
var dupsId=
    from p in list
    group p by p.Id into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g.Key;

var dups= new List<MyObject>();
    foreach (var id in dupsId)
    {
      foreach (var listItem in list.FindAll(p => p.Id== id))
      {
         dups.Add(listItem);
      } 
    }
 dups.ForEach(p=>list.Remove(p));
```

Its'r really remove all duples but i want save one. For example:

```
 list{
   {1,aaaa}
   {2,bbbb}
   {1,aaaa}
   {3,cccc}   
   {1,aaaa}
   {2,bbbb}             
 }
```

And i want to get:

```
 list{
   {1,aaaa}
   {2,bbbb}
   {3,cccc}              
 }
```

How can i modifity my code for this?

Comment: Take a look at the distinct-keyword

Comment: Distinct compare whole object, but i need to compare by one field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the list by `Id` and select the first element from each group

```
var distinctList = list.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(y => y.First());
```

Answer (score 3):

As per your comment you want to compare by `ID` only, have a look at [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) and use the DistinctBy operator and select distinct objects by id. That is something like below

```
var distinct = items.DistinctBy( i => i.Id );
```

Answer (score 1):

Create equality comparer:

```
public sealed class myObjectEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<myObject>
{
    public bool Equals(myObject x, myObject y)
    {
        // null checking here

        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(myObject obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and use it in `Distinct` method:

```
        var uniqueItems = list
            .Distinct(new myObjectEqualityComparer());
```